# Drupal 7 -- Publishing and Printing Content Based on Search Results

Tags: search, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am currently working on a project which requires content to be published onto a view or page depending on a search result criteria.  For example: I search through my content for the word dog and this word appears on 4 of 20 pieces of content.  I wish to view all of those items on a page that is not the *Search Results* page, but rather one that displays all the content found, so I can print each piece of content.

I apologize if this post is awkwardly worded.  At this moment it is just an idea and I am trying to get a better picture of how to change publishing based on search results to a certain area.

Thank you for your time -- and if anyone wishes to ask follow up questions, I'd be more than willing to help clarify.

Comment: Try views with exposed filter!

Comment: I will try that, however what exactly are you referring to when you say "exposed filter".  Are you talking about the "exposed form", "contextual filters", or something entirely different within the view's display?

Comment: None of them! I am talking about the 'filters'! You need to expose those filters to users!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view with exposed filter. Create a view, create a filter criteria there, then in settings - check "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it". A user will see a form in a view, wich you can also make separate from a view, by setting "exposed form" to "yes" and putting it in a sepparate block.